# How to get IntPtr of c# unsafe struct to free its memory initialized in c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, dll

Please, advise me on how to free memory from the created `unsafe` C# `struct`(s) using some standard C# toolset or how get I get the `IntPtr` of those objects to use the default provided custom C++ library?

**The problem details (UPD):**

1. I create the C# `unsafe struct` and pass it to C++ dll that I can't change `TH_ExtractBimTemplate(ref createdStruct)`. The dll updates its content. And in addition to that, the dll saves the reference to the struct object inside of it in an internal list. Here is the struct definition:

   ```cs
   public unsafe struct BIM_Template 
   { 
       public ushort ImageSizeX; 
       public ushort ImageSizeY; 
       public fixed uint Mint[MAX_MINUTIAE_SIZE]; 
       public uint Reserve; 
   }
   ```
2. After the API call returns, I use the data in the struct populated by the C++ dll in my C# code.
3. I need to free the memory used by the struct and C++. The dll has an API to do this, `TH_FreeMemory`.

For step #3 I need to pass the object reference (I presume `IntPtr`) to C++ library or I need to Free the memory it was occupying with some C# instrument.

The Garbage Collection doesn't work even if there are no reference in my C# code to the object, I assume, because of the struct object reference is stored in the list in the dll that I don't control. When `TH_FreeMemory` on the struct object is called, it removes it from the list and release the memory with `delete`, but I can't generate the C# `IntPtr` to pass it to the `TH_FreeMemory` for that...

How can I do that - release the memory with just C# tools, ignoring the list dll or generate the `IntPtr` for this struct?

**The implementation details:**

This is how I create and initialize it:

```cs
BIM_Template template = default;
var template = TH_ExtractBimTemplate(ref template)
```

Where `TH_ExtractBimTemplate(...)` is the method that is pulled from the C++ dll in this way:

```cs
[DllImport("TemplateHelper.dll")]
private static extern int TH_ExtractBimTemplate(
ref BIM_Template out_template);
```

The `TemplateHelper.dll` provides me a C++ method to release the memory - `TH_FreeMemory`:

```cpp
int WINAPI TH_FreeMemory( void *memblock,  BIM_MemBlockType memblock_type )
```

This is how I plug it into C#

```cs
[DllImport("TemplateHelper.dll")]
    private static extern int TH_FreeMemory(
    IntPtr memblock, BIM_MemBlockType memblock_type
);
```

**Current solutions I tried:**

- I need `IntPtr` of the created `unsafe struct` (the template variable) but I don't know how to get it, to free allocated memory with `TH_FreeMemory` dll method
- I have tried to create a bunch of these `unsafe struct` type templates in the method that create them and return void, leaving no references to the created templates, but the garbage collector doesn't free memory. I assume that is, because of the object type is `unsafe struct`. At least, I've waited for 40 minutes and memory wasn't released.
- I have tried the approach below to release the memory with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr ptr)` but that doesn't reduce the amount of unmanaged memory used by the app as well here is the code:

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestDisposalIsCalledOnOutOfContext()
{
    // Create templates
    var templates = LoadTemplates(m, Output);
    // Release the allocated memory using Marshal 
    templates.ForEach( t => MarshaFreeMemory(ref t));
    // Wait
    Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(hours: 1, 0, 0)); 
}

private static IntPtr MarshaFreeMemory(ref BIM_Template? template) 
{
    IntPtr ptr;
    ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<BIM_Template>()); 
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(template, ptr, true);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    
    return ptr;
}
```

```
private static List<BIM_Template?> LoadTemplates() 
{
    var templates = new List<BIM_Template?>();

    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) templates.Add(LoadTemplate()); 
    
    return templates;
}

public static BIM_Template LoadTemplate() 
{
    BIM_Template template = default;
    var template = TH_ExtractBimTemplate(ref template);

    return template;
}
```

So, the question is how can I prevent these memory leaks and free memory from the created templates using some standard C# toolset or how get I get the `IntPtr` of the template object to use the library?

Comment: What does `TH_ExtractBimTemplate` do and return?

Comment: It returns 0 if it was executed with no errors. It get the Template (which is c# usafe struct) and fills it in with the data.

Comment: The library does not return you anything to free, so you are not supposed to free anything. If the library expects that you tell it to free something that it has allocated inside, then consult the documentation on how to do that. If `TH_FreeMemory` expects the same pointer that was originally passed to `TH_ExtractBimTemplate`, and will then free the memory internally associated with that pointer, then you need to make sure that pointer exists in the first place, for which you need to pin the instance of your structure with `GCHanlde` for its entire existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need to call `TH_FreeMemory`. Your structure doesn’t have any pointers inside. In C++, the `Mint` field should be `std::array<uint32_t, MAX_MINUTIAE_SIZE>` or an equivalent.

Your `template` local variable is on the stack, it does not use any heap memory, and the stack memory will be freed automatically just before the `LoadTemplate()` method returns.

if you wanna free the memory used by the list in `TestDisposalIsCalledOnOutOfContext`, do this:

```
templates = null;
// Collect all generations of memory
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Hi @Soonts, thank you for your answer. I've consulted with guys who created the `.dll` it turns out, that it saves and keeps the reference to the struct object, when it first get it via ref in `TH_ExtractBimTemplate(...)` method. So it looks like the only way to solve that is to get the `IntPtr` for this structure, to pass it to `.dll`'s FreeMemory method. What do you think?

Comment: @EugeneShevchuk “saves and keeps the reference to the struct object” — in this case the code will inevitably crash. To fix, replace the C# projection of `TH_ExtractBimTemplate` to take `IntPtr` instead of `ref BIM_Template`, and ask your C++ developer how exactly are you supposed to allocate the memory to make it compatible with their `TH_FreeMemory` function. They probably have some `TH_AllocateMemory` exported from that DLL.